# Django rest API Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have created a REST API using Django rest framework to save details of 'Contact-Me' form  which contains name, mobile no, email and message in UI.
How should I authenticate my API to save the details with out having username and password from my website?

Appreciate your help!!!

Thanks,
Venkat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow any connection to a specific view, you can add `permission.AllowAny` to the `permission_classes` attribute.

```
from rest_framework import permissions
class YourView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permission.AllowAny]
```

Or you can provide it for all your project by default in `settings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': []
}
```

If not specified, this setting defaults to allowing unrestricted access:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
]
```

More info can be found in the [official doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Comment: This would make my API vulnerable right? Is there any other way to authenticate only calls from specific domain?  For example if someone hits the service from Postman multiple times this saves data into my production server and is there any way to eliminate this?

Comment: Yes, you may use a package called [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) to control the cors of your project

Comment: I added django-cors-headers, but still I am able to trigger the service from POSTMAN. Is there anything that I need to  do?  Apart from adding cors, is there any other option to control malicious attacks?

Comment: Well, I don't know the purpose but you why you don't use token to authenticate and control who accesses your API?

Comment: In our case I won't have a token as the user is not registered with us. The domain is available to all across internet and they should be able to fill few basic details and click 'Contact Me' button which should trigger our API and save the details into DB and the call center team will contact the person.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove authenticate permissions

```
settings.py: 
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

Comment: This would make my API vulnerable right? Is there any other way to authenticate only calls from specific domain?  For example if someone hits the service from Postman multiple times this saves data into my production server and is there any way to eliminate this?